# UITableViewCell not clickable when Blinking animation is implemented on it

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, animation, uitableviewrowaction

No action is performed on UITableViewCell when blinking animation is implemented, it starts blinking that is fine but not clickable or swipable. I have tried some solutions but unable to fix it. Code is below.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        
            cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.colorWithHexString(hexStr: "#FDFAEB")
            cell.blink()

        return cell
    }
```

Animation extension code:

```
extension UIView {
    func blink() {
        self.alpha = 0.5;
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.7, //Time duration you want,
                       delay: 0.0,
                       options: [.curveEaseInOut, .autoreverse, .repeat],
                       animations: { [weak self] in self?.alpha = 1.0 },
                       completion: { [weak self] _ in self?.alpha = 0.8 })
    }
}
```

Please tell me, what is the reason, and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default user interaction is disabled during animations. you need to add the  `.allowUserInteraction` option to your set of options.

(And note that if you're animating a view's position the user won't be able to tap on the view as it moves. Behind the scenes, a view jumps to it's destination position as soon as the animation begins. It only appears to move across the screen. If you want to handle tapping on a view as it moves across the screen it's a lot more complicated.)

Comment: Thanks, you saved my day, I added .allowUserInteraction in animation options, and it worked.